# Unity iOS deployment error: Codesign error, can't found .ipa file

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, ipa, codesign

Trying to deploy a Card Game, developed in **Unity** C#, to Test Flight i'm getting this error while validating the archived build.

[Validating codesign error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtVOy.png)

I currently have my Apple account credentials up to date and installed locally, the only two steps i do after Unity -> Xcode export was:

- Setting up bundle id as the iTunes connect app.
- Deleting ***libiconv.2.dylib*** wich wasn't founded by Unity and everyone says that should be deleted. Anyway, i try archiving before deleting this file and was the same.

I read a lot about this and every people get this error while trying to add some Plugins bundles to compilation, but actually is not my case beacuse we are not using any plugin. This are my Frameworks (everything natively exported from Unity):

[Project Frameworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4AAf.png)

I'm currently stuck with this and can't upload my builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved my very frustrating problem. After tons of log reviewing, i noticed that the **sign process was confused with some of my old distribution certificates**.

1. I deleted all my distribution certificates from Keychain Access.
2. Deleted from [developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/](http://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/).
3. Generated new ones.
4. Download and apply to the deploy process and everything works!